# Listview double click (VB .net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web

I have two listview boxes and I want to add **double click** event on it for example if I double click on listview item1 then item should be added on listview2

*HitTest is not working because it is not windows form application*

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind Double Click event through javascript:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] != null && Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "addItem")
    {            
        ListItem itm = ls1.SelectedItem;
        ls1.Items.Remove(itm);

        ls2.SelectedIndex = -1;
        ls2.Items.Add(itm);
    }
    ls1.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(ls1, "addItem"));
```

Comment: He doesn't _need_ to, but it's an option. The backend VB.NET code can also subscribe to those events.

Comment: @Sanya : Google _"C# to VB.NET converter"_. Though I would rather subscribe to those events the normal way (i.e `<asp:ListView ondblclick="ListView1_DoubleClick" ...>`).

Comment: i know the conversion part I am asking how can I do it with the events u r talking about